# Displaying Data in Detail View Controller

Tags: ios, database, uitableview, swift

I am making an app in which there is a database for of hotels which contains (h_name, h_address, h_tariff, h_phone and h_latitude and h_longitude to display that hotel on the map).

So, here's the deal! I successfully retrieved the hotel names in json encode using PHP web service and they are visible in my tableview cells. But, what I need is, when a user taps on one of the hotels then a new view open (specifically detail view controller) with the hotel details and a map view. And, I am trying to get the Hotel Name, Address, Tariff and Phone details in that detail view controller for that particular hotel, also I want to plot the hotel location in Map View using the latitudes and longitudes.

This is my challenge how to retrieve the hotel details.
Here's the ViewControllers Code:

```
import UIKit

class HotelViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var hotelTableView: UITableView!

// Table Data

var hotelArray:[String] = [String]()

var selectedHotel:String?

var hotelName:String?
var hotelAddress:String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

// Set view controller as delegate of tableview
self.hotelTableView.delegate = self
self.hotelTableView.dataSource = self

// Get current hotels
self.retrieveHotels("")

 }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

 }


func retrieveHotels(latestHotel:String) {

// Specify the URL of our retrieval web service
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/localHotelsSearch.php")!

// Create a NSURLSession task with completion handler

let task:NSURLSessionDataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data:NSData!, response:NSURLResponse!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

    // Convert the json data into an array

let dataArray:[AnyObject] = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as [AnyObject]

    // Clear the hotel array
    self.hotelArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    // Loop through each dictionary in the array
    for data in dataArray {

        let dictionary:[String:String] = data as [String:String]

        // Append it to the hotel array
        if dictionary["h_name"] != nil {
            self.hotelArray.append(dictionary["h_name"]!)
        }
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        // Refresh the table
        self.hotelTableView.reloadData()
    }

})

// Run the task
task.resume()
 }

// MARK: - Tableview Delegate Methods

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

// Get a cell

let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("hotelCell") as UITableViewCell


// Configure the cell

cell.textLabel?.text = hotelArray[indexPath.row]

// Return the cell
return cell
 }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

return self.hotelArray.count

 }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

// Keep track of which article the user selcted

self.selectedHotel = self.hotelArray[indexPath.row]

// trigger the segue to go to the detail view
//  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toHotelDetailViewSegue", sender: self)
}



override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

// Get reference to destination view controller

let detailHVC = segue.destinationViewController as HotelDetailViewController

let myIndexPath = self.hotelTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
let row = myIndexPath?.row

// Pass along the selected articles

detailHVC.hotelToDisplay = self.selectedHotel

 }

}
```

Also, here's the Detail View Controller's code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class HotelDetailViewController: UIViewController {

var hotelToDisplay:String?

@IBOutlet weak var hName_dv: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var hAddress_dv: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var hTariff_dv: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var hContact_dv: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a Hotel object with which to store the Hotel data, so right now you are only adding the Hotel Name to your data array.

Create a Hotel Class file

```
class Hotel {
    var name : String? 
    var latitude : Double?

    // etc.
}
```

then in your data method, add the Hotel objects to your data array

```
// Loop through each dictionary in the array
for data in dataArray {

    let dictionary:[String:String] = data as [String:String]

    // Append it to the hotel array
    if dictionary["h_name"] != nil {

        // *You are only adding the hotel NAME to your data array here
        // The other data in the dictionary is not being used, Instead capture all of the data you require from your request

       var h = Hotel()
       h.name = dictionary["h_name"]!
       h.latitude = dictionary["h_latitude"]!

       self.hotelArray.append(h)
    }
}
```

Then use the hotelarray to populate the new ViewController

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

// Get reference to destination view controller

let detailHVC = segue.destinationViewController as HotelDetailViewController

let myIndexPath = self.hotelTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
let row = myIndexPath?.row

// Pass along the selected data, you will need to create these variables in your HotelDetailViewController as well in order to set them
   let hotelToPass = self.hotelArray[row]
   detailHVC.hotelToDisplay = hotelToPass
   detailHVC.hotelName = hotelToPass.name
   detailHVC.hotelLatitude = hotelToPass.latitude 

 }
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your response!

I got everything but have slight confusion in #4.

I did call a $sql query to retrieve the h_name, h_address, h_tariff and h_phone. 
But, I am not getting it, that how should I code that to make it display in detailViewController. - I'M New to iOS.

As, you can see in the HotelViewController, I called a php web service and retrieved the data from the database in json format i.e. in an array of dictionaries.

How would you do this, if you were to display the specific data (name, address, tariff etc.) from these dictionaries in the HotelDetailViewController?

Comment: I edited the response above to address your question more specifically. Let me know if that makes sense now!